# Redisplay the LoginForm when authentication fails

Tags: python, django

This is my login view:

```
def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    redirect('/')
                else:
                    # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                    return render_to_response('message.html', {...})
            else:
                # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
                ???

    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {
        'form': form,
        })
```

And this is my LoginForm class:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=128)
```

The missing part is `# Return an 'invalid login' error message.
                    ???`

How can I redisplay the form with the error message saying invalid login?

Comment: Django has a default login view prepared for you. You might reuse it or read the source and get some inspiration: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show form errors you should use `{{ form.name_of_field.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. In your case you can:

```
    ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        message = 'Your message'

return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {
    'form': form, 'message': message
    })
```

You can also remove unnecessary `if request.method == 'POST':` using: `form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace ??? with pass. LoginForm object that is created at line three contains the errors. Modify templates to show the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an error message and render the same template. You need to pass error message to template so that it is displayed somewhere.

Something like this:

```
def sign_in(request):
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message
            error = "Invalid username/password."
            #if you want to keep provided username, but clear password field
            form = LoginForm(initial={'username': request.POST.get('username')})

    ...
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {
        'form': form, 'error': error
        })
```

Update template to show `error` appropriately.